# Spring boot is not loading the application.yml from BOOT-INF/classes path from application jar

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a application.yml with Jenkins build information under BOOT-INF/classes in application jar . When try to hit /info endpoint ,app is not displaying build info

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, when you make a question, try to give as much details as possible. Your problem is crystal clear but there is no further detail: research, what did you try...

Comment: Can you please add you pom.xml file here?